# How to solve a differential equation with a power (third degree diff eq?)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to solve this equationn but I really don't see what to do with the term with the power. Can someone give me a hint to help me solve this kind of equation please? (I'm not asking for a solution, just a hint, to at least be able to begin solving myself) Is there something obvious that I don't see because I'm focusing too much on the power? Here is the equation :

for $x\in [0,m]$, A, B, C and D constants :

$A\frac{d^4y(x)}{dx^4}+By(x)^3=0$

with boundary conditions :

$y(0)=0$

$A\frac{d^2y(0)}{dx^2}=C\frac{dy(0)}{dx}$

$\frac{d^2y(m)}{dx^2}=0$

$A\frac{d^3y(m)}{dx^3}=D$

Thank you

Comment: You are correct to regard the power. This is a non-linear differential equation, and no general method exists to solve them. This one also looks tough. Hopefully someone can figure something out.

Comment: i think there is no solution which containes the known elementary functions

Comment: What form of solution does the task seek? For a numerical solution any boundary value solver should work, with all the solvability and uniqueness questions that entails.